# SQL query returns null in PHP, but correct result in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, auto-increment

I'm building a web application for inserting data into a MySQL database. I'm using PHP's PDO API to query the database to obtain an auto-incrementing primary key. When I run the query in MySQL Console, it produces the correct output. But when I try to run the query in PHP, it returns null.

Query:

```
mysql> SELECT Auto_Increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='charlist';
```

Result in MySQL console:

```
+----------------+
| Auto_Increment |
+----------------+
|              7 |
+----------------+
```

Relevant PHP code:

```
    // Configuration.
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $dbname = "asoiaf";
    $tablename = "charlist";

    // Opens a connection to the database.
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getmessage();
    }

    // Gets all the information from POST.
    $autoidquery = "SELECT Auto_Increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='$tablename'";
    $id = $conn->query("SELECT Auto_Increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='$tablename'");
    // This should output the auto-incremented primary key, but nothing is output.
    echo $id."<br>Hello world";
```

Nothing is output on the page, although it should output the auto-incremented id and then "Hello world". I can't see any typos that I've made. Why would the query work in the console, but not in PHP?

Comment: I believe `$id` in this case would be a result set, so try accessing it using `$id[0]['Auto_Increment']`. Or, try doing `var_dump($id)`, to see exactly what the variable contains.

Comment: What, like this? `echo $id[0]['Auto_Increment'];` That also didn't output anything :/.

Comment: Interesting. When I did var_dump, it output the following, and I have no idea what it means: `object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(80) "SELECT Auto_Increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='charlist'" }`.

Comment: @Sean, why did you delete your answer? I tried your code, it worked and solved my problem. I was just about to accept it.

Comment: @LeoKing sorry about that. Meant to click on edit, but hit delete, and then my wifi dropped. I have reinstated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the result

```
$qry = $conn->query("SELECT Auto_Increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE  table_name='$tablename'");
$result = $qry->fetch();
$id = $result['Auto_Increment'];
echo $id."<br>Hello world";
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Great!

Answer (score 1):

[PDO Query returns a PDO Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php), to access the desired result you need to access the result as an array.

```
echo $id['Auto_Increment'];
```

Or you could fetch the result from the statement

```
echo $id->fetchColumn();
```

Or use [PDO Prepare + fetchColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) to retrieve the result as an integer.

Many ways lead to rome ;)

Answer (score 1):

use :
    print_r($id);

to see the content of query result . the output of the query result is an array. you shou